# Get CCNode/CCSprite within FOR statement

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccnode

I have numerous CCNodes that all have the same query run on them. I am trying to stream line the code and am wondering if its possible to get the CCNodes within a FOR statement.

For example if I had the CCNodes references within a NSArray like

```
NSArray *exampleArray = @[@"Mercedes-Benz", @"BMW", @"Porsche", @"Opel", @"Volkswagen", @"Audi"];
```

How would I references them within a FOR Statement?

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {

      //Get CCNode reference
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you store CCNode references in array and then use foreach

Comment: @InderKumarRathore how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your object are added to some parent easiest would be to:

```
CCNode *node;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(wrapperObject.children, node)
{
  [node runAction:xxx];
}
```

Within loop you could add condition to check for class of node if you need some constraints.

If you want to create sprites and add them to some parent than you could:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [exampleArray count]; i++)
{
  CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFileName:exampleArray[i]];
//set position and other properties
  [parentObject addChild:sprite];
}
```

Comment: I dont understand the first example. It doesn't seem to work.